# How to translate "used to"?

Tags: single-word-requests

How does one translate "used to"?

But this definition:

**use:**

2. describing an action or state of affairs that was done repeatedly or existed for a period in the past.

Examples:

- "You used to call me on my cellphone"
- "I used to go there everyday"

Would *kutime* be acceptable here?

as in *mi kutime iris tien ĉiutage* for "I used to go there everyday"

Answer (score 4):

Actually, *kutimi* is a verb. PIV defines it as follows:

> Havi fortan emon al ia ago pro ofta ripetado.

and gives one example:

- Li kutimas fumi pipon post tagmanĝo.

Your sentences would be:

- Vi kutimis alvoki min ...
- Mi kutimis iri tien ĉiutage.

Comment: Translation of the PIV quote would be appreciated. And also, how do you say "call me on my cellphone" i Esperanto? Maybe another question for that is necessary...

Comment: Maybe "call me on my cellphone" would be "alvoki mian poŝtelefonon". Sorry, I just remembered that "Hotline Bling" had an example of what I was trying to ask about.

Comment: Ah, yes maybe that works.

Comment: To call by a telephone is _telefoni_, not some form of _voki_ (to call by name or to demand an action).

Comment: @Juha Metsäkallas Laux kion mi lernis,  ”telefoni” signifas ”paroli kun iu per telefono” kaj ”alvoki” signifas ”iniciati al telefonado kun iu”. Du personoj telefonas, sed nur unu alvokis kaj la alia estis alvokita. Gravas la distingo, mi pensas, por la kazoj kiam la alvoko ne ricevas respondon.

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro, [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#telefoni) havas ekzemplojn: "telefoni novaĵon" kaj "ne skribu, telefonu!", kiuj miakomprene klare montras, ke oni inciatas la telefonadon. Plie nek PIV nek Reta vortaro havas ekzemplojn rilataj al telefonado por la vorto "voki" aŭ "alvoki".

Answer (score 4):

You can use *kutim-* in any form, or *rutino* for a routine, or just add *ofte* or *de tempo al tempo*.

> *Vi kutimis min telefoni. Kutime vi telefonis. Estis via kutimo telefoni.*
>
> *Vi havis rutinon poŝtelefoni min.*
>
> *Ofte vi vokis min tra mia poŝtelefono. Ofte vi vokis min telefone.*

Be aware that *(al)voki X* might be misunderstood as "ask X to come".

For "you would..." you can also use *-ad-*.

> *De tempo al tempo vi vokadis min telefone.*

Your example, *Mi kutime iris tien ĉiutage*, is correct, although I think *ĉiutage* would cover the fact that it was a *kutimo*.

Answer (score 3):

*Kutime* could work in the examples you provided. Wells also suggests *iam*. The first suggestion that sprang to my mind was *antaŭe*, which is also what Benson (CEED) suggests.

Comment: _antaŭe_ was my first thought too, but it doesn't have the connotation of "repeatedly/regularly" that the asker is after.

Comment: Neither does *iam*. As I often say in my answers, ultimately you need to express ideas, not translate words. If *antaŭe* doesn't quite catch your meaning, it can be clarified in other ways - such as with *-adis* or certain adverbs.